# IMPORTHTML() doesn't work in this webpage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import data from a table from the following page:

https://basketballmonster.com/playerrankings.aspx

When I do so, with all players filter selected, only the top players are imported to my googlesheet. Can someone help me achieve this? Appreciation in advance.

I attached the googlesheet below for your review:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uvhNp6gBnnEvs8CBb4K7onccew_doFp96wmFEsYyLBk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets can't know what your browser has, so it doesn't know whether you selected which filter. You have to get the same html for Sheets that you have displayed in your browser, which means adding the filter in your query.

Since it looks like the controls aren't passed as parameters in a GET request, sadly it's not as simple as appending
`?PlayerFilterControl=TopPlayers` to the url.

You have to POST it as a payload with a post request like
`{ 'PlayerFilterControl': 'AllPlayers'}`.

Sadly Google Sheets IMPORTHTML() doesn't support post request yet, so you'll have to get into apps scripts, request and xml parsing.

I suggest you check out these:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service

Comment: I will try to look into this- this is definitely not in my wheelhouse so I may just have to copy and paste it into the sheet.